# Почему символ "\xD3" превращается в "\xC3" после скачивания файла и как предотвратить это?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть функция для скачивания файла с текстом text и названием файла filename

```js
     function download_file_with_content(filename, text) {
         var element = document.createElement('a');
         
         element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
         element.setAttribute('download', filename);

         element.style.display = 'none';
         document.body.appendChild(element);

         element.click();

         document.body.removeChild(element);
     }
```

Напишу допустим код такой:

```js
download_file_with_content('test.txt', '\xD3')
```

Попробуйте открыть файл через HxD и увидите что он записал явно не значение '\xD3'(число 211) а '\xC3'(Число 195)

С чем это может быть связано? Или если это не объяснимо, то какие варианты решения данной проблемы могут быть? Я пробовал также загружать при помощи blob и mime-type=octet-stream

Comment: С тем, что в javascript-строках записываются **символы в юникоде**, `\xd3` то же самое что и `\u00d3` — это код символа **Ó**, а при кодировании в UTF-8 из этого одного символа получается **два байта** `\xc3\x93` которые вы и видите

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос, какую кодировку мне использовать чтобы в итоге он записал двоичный код "как есть"?

Comment: Либо как можно не используя строки получить файл с двоичными своими заданными байтами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы занести символ в файл без всяких преобразований в utf8 требуется использовать ArrayBuffer и Blob

Записываем символ числом

```
var arrbuf = new ArrayBuffer(1) 
 var uint8 = new Uint8Array(arrbuf) 
 uint8[0] = 211
```

После этого создаём Blob

```
var blb = new Blob([strleft, arrbuf, strright])
```

После этого мы скачиваем файл уже не через text-plain и что-то ещё а используем функцию `URL.createObjectURL(blb)`

Тогда итоговое решение проблемы становится так:

```
element.setAttribute('href', URL.createObjectURL(blb))
```